# Measuring total request time in Chrome - wrong total time

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

What could be the reason that the total time of a request is higher than the Connection Setup time + Request/Response time?

[image]

357.32ms > (19.04 + 0.56 + 8.56 + 23.46 + 0.41)ms

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe `Explanation` measures time passed since the page started loading? Can you show more of the waterfall?

Comment: You may be right, I will check it out, `Explanation` is a link to Google explanations.
EDIT: Checked, the next request has lower total time, so it may not be it

Comment: @Ofiris Are you able to reproduce this mismatch/provide a link to a page that causes it?

Comment: @Gideon After several tests, I couldn't reproduce this issue

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. @Ofiris did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I think it was something related to some cache in the browser, restart helped, iirc.

Comment: found a way to solve, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case I noticed that the "gap" was always after the "DNS lookup" as shown below. Somehow Chrome couldn't measure the time taken to translate `localhost into`127.0.0.1`

I solved the problem by replacing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in the URL bar. This removed 80%~90% of the overall load time

[image]